# How to count dictionaries in a MongoDB array?

Tags: python, mongodb, count, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection, where each document is someone's demographic information (a unique identifier, name, address, etc).

As I parse new data into my database using Python/pymongo, I find new entries corresponding to existing identifiers, and I need to keep track of the new entries' counts in order to only utilize the most common one in the end.

For example, if I already have "Jenn Smith" in my collection, and then I get two new entries for "Jennifer Smith" and the same identifier, it is the same person and I just use Mongo's `$inc` to increment a counter, so the document eventually looks like: `'names': { 'Jenn Smith': 1, 'Jennifer Smith': 2}` - And I can use "Jennifer Smith" which is the most common one in the end.

My problem arises when I have to deal with the exact same issue with the locations that Jenn Smith has associated with herself, because `location` is a dictionary, for example: `{'street': '123 Maple Street Apt A', 'city': 'Austin', 'state': 'TX'}`. Now it happens that sometimes I get several different locations, each one a dictionary, that so far I `$push` into a Mongo `locations` array. However, in the majority of cases there is a predominant location for each collection document, with any others being slight variations, e.g.: `{'street': '123 Maple Street Apartment A', 'city': 'Austin', 'state': 'TX'}`.

I understand that `$inc` can't work the same way as for `names`, since Python dictionaries aren't hashable. How should I go about finding the most common element in my `locations` array?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `dictionary` is not nested you can create a `frozon set` of your `dictionary` and `hash` it:

```
hash(frozenset(location.items()))
```